# Understanding find function on an Enumerable in Ruby

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I am reading "Practical Ruby for System Administration" by Andre Ben Hanou, which has a one-liner that lists all files in a directory whose size is bigger than 1KB and then sorted by the modification date.

```
ruby -e 'puts Dir["*"].find { |f| File.size(f) > 1024 }.sort_by{|f| File.mtime(f)}'
```

I think that it should be `select` instead of `find`.

According to the documentation for `find`, it returns the first for which the block is not false. So, `find` will never return a list of files in any case. It's like the 19th page in the book, and I am completely new to Ruby, and I think that the author is wrong because the command in the book gives me an error already.

```
shadyabhi@archlinux /tmp $ ruby -e 'puts Dir["*"].find { |f| File.size(f) > 1024 }.sort_by{|f| File.mtime(f)}'
-e:1:in `<main>': undefined method `sort_by' for "mysql-security-excerpt-5.1-en.pdf":String (NoMethodError)
shadyabhi@archlinux /tmp $
```

Can anyone confirm that the author is wrong or I am just being plain stupid?

Comment: There are numerous answers on SO explaining how blocks can be passed to functions. Because SO wants a single question, and not several, you should remove that separate question, do some searching to get more information and see if blocks will make sense. Read the "Methods and Blocks" section of "[Programming Ruby](Methods and Blocks)", which talks about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, it should be `.select` (or its alias `.find_all`, which may be the reason for this error).

In this case the block is evaluated for each object, here is a tutorial: 
    http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_blocks.htm

Comment: Thanks for telling about `find_all`.

Answer (score 2):

> lists **all** files

Yes, the author is wrong, and you're right. It should be `.select`, not `.find`.